# Error while updating property 'initialRegion' of a view managed by: AIRMap

Tags: reactjs, react-native, google-maps, expo, react-native-maps

I am creating an app with `expo` where I require map.  I explored and found the `mapView` component in `react-native-maps` npm package. I installed it and just added the below code in a new component from their documentation only [see](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-maps). But it is showing this error:

```
Error while updating property 'initialRegion' of a view managed by: AIRMap
```

**code**

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import {  StyleSheet,  Text,  View} from "react-native";
import MapView from "react-native-maps";

const Map = () => {

  return (

    <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text style={styles.text}>
            Maps
        </Text>
        <MapView
           initialRegion={{
           latitude: 37.78825,
           longitude: -122.4324,
           latitudeDelta: 0.0922,
           longitudeDelta: 0.0421,
        }}
       />
      </View>   
  )
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex:1,
        justifyContent:'center',
        alignItems:'center'
    },
    text:{
        fontSize:40,
        margin:40,
    }
})
export default Map;
```

And I still found this error

[image: Screenshot_2022-06-09-17-43-44-46_f73b71075b1de7323614b647fe394240]

##### How to solve this?

Comment: Did you follow the full installation guide? https://github.com/react-native-maps/react-native-maps/blob/HEAD/docs/installation.md

Comment: Also, few solutions here that worked for most users with the same error: https://github.com/react-native-maps/react-native-maps/issues/140

Comment: See, the last one is my issue only in the given link

Comment: Also I am using expo and the project is not having any `Android` related files.

Answer (score 2):

If using Expo, remember to install react-native-maps with this command:

```
expo install react-native-maps
```

Credits: https://github.com/react-native-maps/react-native-maps/issues/140#issuecomment-1127347250

Answer (score 0):

I also encountered this error but then after setting up my google maps and updating my import like so:

```
import MapView, { PROVIDER_GOOGLE, Marker } from 'react-native-maps';
```

It seemed to solve the problem.

Here is the tutorial I followed: https://instamobile.io/react-native-tutorials/uber-react-native-geolocation/

Answer (score 0):

npm unistall react-native-maps
npm install react-native-maps@^0.30.2
the older version seems to work

Comment: Hi, I would personally add this as a comment since it's not a fix. It's a workaround to get it working

Answer (score 0):

Setup 1: Create APK Your blank project. Use This Code:

```
eas build --profile development --platform android
```

Setup 2:

```
expo install expo-ads-admob
```

Setup 3:

```
expo start --dev-client
```

Ref this code: [code link](https://github.com/BhavsarKrutarth/GoogleAds/blob/main/App.js)

Ref link : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=myDDG54OvkE&t=150s